# angular click on div to change background

Tags: html, angular

HTML

```html
<div class="div2" *ngFor="let row of customer" (click)="showMessege(row.jobid)" [style.class.secondary]="changecolor">            
    <h3>ID : {{row.jobid}} </h3>
    <p>Date : {{date}}</p>           
</div>
```

In .ts file

```js
changecolor = false
showMessege(ids:string){    
    this.id = ids
    console.log(id)
    this.shared.travelID(id)
    this.changecolor = true    
    this.shared.notiCount(0)    
}
```

.css

```css
.secondary {
    background-color: red        
}
```

Result should be change background color from nothing to red if I click on each div.

But now if I click on some div it **all red** at the same time even some div is not clicked.

In this example it's changed to grey each row if clicked
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xd3yss

I try to change div to table but I still all red even don't clicked.

Comment: because you change the variable for the whole component. You need to store the info for each row and only change it on this one row.

Comment: I think I found the ways

Comment: it's only `[class.secondary]="variable"` -remove the "style"- (if variable is true the class is applied). Another way can be `[ngClass]="variable?'secondary':null`

Comment: I try to do read/unread message